# $\prod_{k=0}^\infty p_k > 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p_k) < \infty$

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $\{p_k\}$ be a probability mass sequence. Is it true that
if $\prod_{k=0}^\infty p_k > 0$ then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p_k) < \infty$?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that my question does not make sense, because if $\{p_k\}$ is a probability mass sequence, then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k = 1$, but then $\prod_{k=0}^\infty p_k$ cannot be greater than $0$. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product, especially the section "Convergence criteria".